# Sublime 3 JSHint Gutter always show error at the bottom

Tags: configuration, package, settings, sublimetext3, jshint

I'm used to Atom's JSHint always showing the first error on the bottom (so if there's errors on lines 1, 3, 4, it will show the error on line 1 at bottom left hand corner and then show the one on line 3 once line 1's error is resolved and so on and so forth), can I customize Sublime 3 JSHint Gutter to do the same for me automatically? Because currently I have to click on each red squiggly in the editor in order for the error to show up on the bottom left hand corner instead of it appearing automatically.